# Pulling Trending Data WeeK Over Week

Tags: mysql

I am trying to pull some sums week over week, and the query I have built gets the data, but is horrificaly slow.

```
 SELECT app_client_id
 , (SELECT COUNT(b.app_id) FROM `li_appointments` AS b
         WHERE YEARWEEK(b.app_datetime) = YEARWEEK(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 WEEK))
         AND b.app_client_id = a.app_client_id)
 , (SELECT COUNT(b.app_id) FROM `li_appointments` AS b
         WHERE YEARWEEK(b.app_datetime) = YEARWEEK(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -2 WEEK))
         AND b.app_client_id = a.app_client_id)
 FROM `li_appointments` AS a
```

EXPLAIN gives me this:

```
 |id||select_type       ||table||type ||possible_keys||key  ||key_len||ref||rows ||Extra    |
 |1 ||PRIMARY           ||a    ||index|\N             |Extra||18      |\N  |61901||Using index|
 |3 ||DEPENDENT SUBQUERY||b    ||index|\N             |Extra||18      |\N  |61901||Using where; Using index|
 |2 ||DEPENDENT SUBQUERY||b    ||index|\N             |Extra||18      |\N  |61901||Using where; Using index|
```

The table being refrenced is :

```
 create table `li_appointments` (
`app_id` int (11),
`app_datetime` datetime ,
`app_facility` varchar (600),
`app_department` varchar (600),
`app_address` varchar (600),
`app_language` varchar (600),
`app_requesting_person` varchar (600),
`app_service_provider` varchar (600),
`app_client_id` int (11),
`app_client_other` varchar (600),
`app_medicaid_status` int (11),
`app_health_program` varchar (150),
`les_name` varchar (500),
`les_dob` varchar (75),
`les_medicaid_id` varchar (500),
`billing_total_time` time ,
`billing_workorder_received` int (11),
`billing_admin_fee` float ,
`billing_notes` varchar (3000),
`app_notes` varchar (3000),
`created_by` varchar (300),
`created_on` datetime ,
`modified_by` varchar (300),
`modified_on` datetime ,
`wo_entered_by` varchar (300),
`app_callback_num` varchar (135),
`terp_id` varchar (135),
`app_covered_by` varchar (135),
`covered_on` datetime ,
`uofu_csn` varchar (135));
```

Is there a better way to get this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely slow because you all your WHERE clauses are using things like `YEARWEEK(b.app_datetime)` that prevent use indexes and the fact that you are using subselects.

I don't really understand why you are using the subselects though. A simple case statement should eliminate such a need:

```
SELECT
    app_client_id,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN app_datetime > DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 WEEK) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS last_week_count,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN app_datetime > DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 WEEK) THEN 0
            WHEN app_datetime > DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -2 WEEK) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS two_weeks_ago_count    
FROM `li_appointments`
GROUP BY app_client_id
```

Make sure you have an index on `app_client_id`.

It should also be noted that this would provide a rolling week over week data set.  In your original question, you were using `YEARWEEK()` which could have actually provided data for more than a week at a time.  For example Say it is Wednesday and I want to count all items with `YEARWEEK()` equal to last Wednesday.  This would actually match all items from SUN/MON through SAT/SUN of that previous week (week start and end depending on mode your MySQL is running in with regards to week numbering).

If this is in fact what you want, this is even easier to achieve:

```
SELECT
    app_client_id,
    YEARWEEK(app_datetime) AS year_week,
    SUM(1) as weekly_count   
FROM `li_appointments`
GROUP BY `app_client_id`, `year_week`
HAVING `year_week` < YEARWEEK(NOW())
ORDER BY `year_week` DESC
LIMIT 2
```

This would give you data for last two full weeks, but not current week. If you want current week (which might be up to 6 days, 23:59:59 long) just remove the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: i like this (no subqueries necessary), although i think it should be `>=` instead of `>`.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea You might be correct about `>=` vs. `>` it would really depend on whether the OP wants to include or exclude that exact second from `NOW()` to one/two weeks ago.

Comment: I like this it looks really clean, however I am getting this error:Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE
    ) AS last_week_count,
    SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN app_d' at line 7

Comment: its not `END CASE`, its just `END`. also, if you wanted to further improve performance, I'd recommend converting the `DATE_ADD` function to ANSI-compliant format.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm.  Thanks for getting me outside my box.

Comment: @JoelLewis Also just added commentary in case you still wanted to use a data set based on `YEARWEEK()`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the subquery to join like below and see if it improves the performance

```
SELECT 
a.app_client_id,
COUNT(b.app_id) as appid_count
from app_client_id a join
li_appointments b on b.app_client_id = a.app_client_id
where 
YEARWEEK(b.app_datetime) in 
   (
   (YEARWEEK(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 WEEK)),
   (YEARWEEK(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -2 WEEK))
   )
```

Comment: where the year week is both 1 week ago and 2 weeks ago? how many records u think match that requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a subquery with `UNION ALL` setup:

```
SELECT app_client_id
    ,SUM(app_id_count_1_week) AS app_id_count_1_week
    ,SUM(app_id_count_2_weeks) AS app_id_count_2_weeks
FROM (
    SELECT app_client_id
        ,COUNT(app_id) AS app_id_count_1_week
        ,CAST(0 AS INTEGER) AS app_id_count_2_weeks
    FROM li_appointments
    WHERE b.app_datetime >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '7' DAY
    GROUP BY app_client_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT app_client_id
        ,CAST(0 AS INTEGER) AS app_id_count_1_week
        ,COUNT(app_id) AS app_id_count_2_weeks
    FROM li_appointments
    WHERE b.app_datetime >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '14' DAY
    GROUP BY app_client_id
) AS Both_Counts
GROUP BY app_client_id
```

This will do the aggregations as needed separately, `UNION` the results, and then the `SUM` on the top layer will add the actual `COUNT` and 0. The change in the syntax is making the `WHERE` clause ANSI-compliant.

Just an idea off the top of my head.